# How to stop relative paths from being rewritten to absolute paths in Rmarkdown documents?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I just discovered something a bit unusual in how relative paths containing `../` are handled when rendering Rmarkdown documents. Let's say I have a project with a structure as shown below:

```
./
├── files/
│   ├── some_image.jpg
│   └── test.Rmd
└── some_other_image.jpg
```

And I have an Rmarkdown document which I want to render to into HTML containing both jpegs `some_image.jpg` and `some_other_image.jpg`, like so:

```
---
title: "Path Test"
output:
  html_fragment:
    self_contained: false
    keep_md: true
---

Path without ../ is not altered
![Unaltered](some_image.jpg)

Path with ../ is converted to an absolute path!
![Altered](../some_other_image.jpg)
```

If I create the HTML document with `rmarkdown::render("files/test.Rmd", clean = FALSE)`, it produces the following HTML:

```
<p>Path without ../ is not altered <img src="some_image.jpg" alt="Unaltered" /></p>
<p>Path with ../ is converted to an absolute path! <img src="/home/will/test_project/some_other_image.jpg" alt="Altered" /></p>
```

If you look at the `src` attribute for each image, you can see that the image path that was specified using `../` gets rewritten to use an absolute path!!

My questions: Why is this happening? This doesn't happen to me when manually using `pandoc` to convert this very same markdown to HTML? And if you inspect the intermediate markdown file produced, the path to `some_other_image.jpg` is still `../some_other_image.jpg`.

And what can I do to stop it? It works fine on my particular machine of course, but this is a big problem if the page is going to be deployed somewhere else.

I'm running Rmarkdown version 1.0 with R version 3.3.1 on debian testing, in case that's relevant for reproducing.

Comment: When I use your snippet, the relative path is not altered when checking with Chrome. At least for me.

Comment: @Martin I was afraid this would be hard to reproduce. What version of R and what OS are you on? I'm running R 3.3.1 on debian testing.

Comment: R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan) ... all packages up to date (CRAN, no Github versions)

Comment: I can confirm that the second path is converted to an absolute path under R 3.1.1 on Windows 10. Interestingly, this only happens *if the image exists*. If the path points to a nonexistent image, it is not converted.

Comment: That might be the reason why I thought it is not converted!

Comment: @CL. wow that's interesting, good catch, I've only ever tried it with images that do exist, because why would I try to use an image that doesn't =). Looking more and more like an Rmarkdown bug.

Comment: THe basic problem I have with any paths generated when knitting in RMarkdown is that they are not the same as the path that is used if you run the individual chunks in the console.   In the end I always convert to absolute path using `paste0("`","/path/to/file").  The working directory is not the same pretty often because you are in a clean environment.